# ngGrid double click row to open pop-up for editing a row

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

How would I go about implementing a double-click event in ng-Grid? More particularly, I want the double-clicking to open a pop-up modal(Angular UI Modal) for editing.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Add ngDblclick to your rowtemplate. See also in comments here : http://developer.the-hideout.de/?p=113

Answer (score 8):

In ng-grid 2.0.11, do a simply call to ng-dblclick directive in row template

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'gdDtA',
    rowTemplate: '<div ng-dblclick="foo(row)" ng-style="{\'cursor\': row.cursor, \'z-index\': col.zIndex() }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}" ng-cell></div>',        
};

$scope.foo = function(r) {
    console.log(r);
}
```

See in: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating

Comment: Note that you can do this even if you use double click to edit a cell. The function will get called and the cell, if editable, will have the input box opened. This is useful if you have an editable condition and want some cells to pop something up and others to be edited normally.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this getting posted, I'll give it a try instead of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the link in the comment on the question by @AardVark71 [Add Doubleclick Behavior to ng-grid](http://developer.the-hideout.de/?p=113)

Add the following Javascript-File to some dir accessible from your app and don’t forget to load it during startup.

```
/* 
 DoubleClick row plugin
*/

function ngGridDoubleClick() {
    var self = this;
    self.$scope = null;
    self.myGrid = null;

    // The init method gets called during the ng-grid directive execution.
    self.init = function(scope, grid, services) {
        // The directive passes in the grid scope and the grid object which
        // we will want to save for manipulation later.
        self.$scope = scope;
        self.myGrid = grid;
        // In this example we want to assign grid events.
        self.assignEvents();
    };
    self.assignEvents = function() {
        // Here we set the double-click event handler to the header container.
        self.myGrid.$viewport.on('dblclick', self.onDoubleClick);
    };
    // double-click function
    self.onDoubleClick = function(event) {
        self.myGrid.config.dblClickFn(self.$scope.selectedItems[0]);
        self.$scope.$apply();
    };
}
```

Define a function to handle the double-click and update the grid-options as shown here:

```
$scope.myDblClickHandler = function(rowItem) {
// rowItem is actually the entity of the row ...
}

$scope.gridOptions = {
    // other config here...
    dblClickFn: $scope.myDblClickHandler,
    plugins: [ngGridDoubleClick]
}
```

This function does not have to be on the $scope for this to work.

Comment: This approach assumes you have selection enabled for the rows.

Comment: I might be missing something, is there a reason you would do this rather than use the `ng-dblclick` as in @Rodolpho's answer?

Comment: His answer didn't exist when I wrote mine.  I'm planning on trying his answer soon and see if that works better than mine.