# How to factor scope dependent plugins into a service for ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am developing a project that uses ngGrid to enable the user to view and select data.

I am using a couple plugins I have pick up from the community.

- a double click listener taken from [ngGrid double click row to open pop-up for editing a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133550/nggrid-double-click-row-to-open-pop-up-for-editing-a-row) and a filter bar taken from http://plnkr.co/edit/c8mHmAXattallFRzXSaG?p=preview

  ```
  var ngGridDoubleClick =  function() {
      var self = this;
      self.$scope = null;
      self.myGrid = null;

      // The init method gets called during the ng-grid directive execution.
      self.init = function(scope, grid, services) {
          // The directive passes in the grid scope and the grid object which
          // we will want to save for manipulation later.
          self.$scope = scope;
          self.myGrid = grid;
          // In this example we want to assign grid events.
          self.assignEvents();
      };
      self.assignEvents = function() {
          // Here we set the double-click event handler to the header container.
          self.myGrid.$viewport.on('dblclick', self.onDoubleClick);
      };
      // double-click function
      self.onDoubleClick = function(event) {
          self.myGrid.config.dblClickFn(self.$scope.selectedItems[0]);
      };
  }


  var filterBarPlugin = {
      init: function(scope, grid) {
          filterBarPlugin.scope = scope;
          filterBarPlugin.grid = grid;
          $scope.$watch(function() {
              var searchQuery = "";
              angular.forEach(filterBarPlugin.scope.columns, function(col) {
                  if (col.visible && col.filterText) {
                      var filterText = (col.filterText.indexOf('*') == 0 ? col.filterText.replace('*', '') : "^" + col.filterText) + ";";
                      searchQuery += col.displayName + ": " + filterText;
                  }
              });
              return searchQuery;
          }, function(searchQuery) {
              filterBarPlugin.scope.$parent.filterText = searchQuery;
              filterBarPlugin.grid.searchProvider.evalFilter();
          });
      },
      scope: undefined,
      grid: undefined
  };
  ```

I am loading them like this:

```
   $scope.gridOptions = {

            data : 'parts.partlist',
            columnDefs : 'parts_fields',
            dblClickFn : $scope.addToConstruct,
            multiSelect : false,
            showGroupPanel : true,
            jqueryUIDraggable: true,
            plugins: [ filterBarPlugin, ngGridDoubleClick ],
            headerRowHeight : 60,
            sortInfo : SortOpts,
            selectedItems : $scope.selection

    }
```

So the problem is is that these plugin definitions exist in a controller and I would like to pull them out to a service so that I can use them anywhere without copy/pasting ~50 lines of code.

I have tried to put them in a factory but they need access to the $scope object and I was unsuccessful in injecting $scope into my factory.

Any ideas on how to best turn these plugins into reusable components?

Comment: Try directive that can applied on the grid.

Comment: Do you mean somehow wrapping the ng-grid directive ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to inject $scope into your factory, the init() function of the plugin does that for you in this line of each plugin (ref [ngGrid Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Plugins)):

```
self.init = function(scope, grid) {
```

All you have to do is stick them in a factory, and return each function from the factory. I reconfigured filterBarPlugin into a function instead of a JSON object in this case... See sample code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Uw28KUbIOtDps2GaJahb?p=preview

Comment: Oh cool, this is a good way to do it. I ended up making a 'decorator' directive to hold the plugins which works too but this is a better way to hold the 'plugins'.